# Laravel HTTP test to own API adds last part form APP_URL

Tags: php, laravel

Short:
I cannot test my own API, because of the current APP_URL environment variable that I am using.

APP_URL contains http://localhost:8080/foldername, whereas `foldername` is a random string character that is very important to our dev-environment. If I try to run the test from the snippet below, my backend recieves the path like `foldername/api/users` instead of `api/users` - Of course this will not work.

Problem: I cannot change the APP_URL inside the .env file, nor in the phpunit.xml file. I have to solve this programmatically. How can I cut this "foldername" off?

Long:

I wanted to test my own API that I've built in Laravel, but every test failed with "invalid JSON was returned from the route" - which is weird because I know that my API works. (requests with axios do return the correct json)

The test is very basic and looks like this:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase {

    public function test_get_users() {
        $response = $this->json('GET', url('/api/users')); //falsely tests foldername/api/users
        $response->assertJsonCount(1);
    }
}
```

The routes are defined in the routes/api.php file:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

I decided to catch and dump the requested route in one of the used middlewares via `$request->path()`
and got the output mentioned above.

I first tried it without using the built-in url helper, but with even worse results - maybe these errors correlate, but I cannot see how.

```
$this->json('GET', '/api/users'); //received as '/' instead - no route at all
```

Adding this line to the phpunit.xml did not do anything, and even if it did, hardcoded "localhost:8080" won't do. We have many different systems with different app_urls, but every single one has a "foldername" at the end of it, which has to be ignored.

```
<server name="APP_URL" value="http://localhost:8080"/>
```

I altered APP_URL inside my .env file and cleared all caches, which made the tests work, but break the rest of the program.

We use Laravel 6.5 and php 7.4

Comment: Before I do share any solution, I would like to understand while you testing API in local, why you want to remove the `folder name` from the URL?

When you host that folder on the server and make it live with any domain, do you want your API URL structure something like `domain.com/api/users`.?

Comment: @KaushikThakkar No, this has nothing to do with the looks of the published API url. I can request the API from my frontend without any problems. But these http tests do not make actual http requests. I guess the program is called with modified parameters, but what I do not understand is why the `request()->path()` differs so strongly from what I pass to the json method.

Answer (score 0):

Worked around the problem by overriding the setUp method:

```
namespace Tests\Feature;

use Tests\TestCase;

class UserTest extends TestCase {
    use WithFaker;

    public function setUp(): void {
        parent::setUp();
        \URL::forceRootUrl(dirname(env('APP_URL')));
    }

    public function test_create_user() {
        $response = $this->json('GET', url('/api/users'));
        // $response->assertJson(...);
    }
}
```

I still do not understand why my backend gets requested with an empty route "/", when I pass the route how the documentation describes it:

```
$response = $this->json('GET', '/api/users');
```